# Can graph interpolating function, but not use it. Any thoughts?

Tags: differential-equations, evaluation, interpolation

When solving a system of differential equations numerically, I get two interpolating functions. I can graph both of these, but when I try to evaluate either of the functions at a point, it just spits out:

```
{x1[5]}
```

`x1[t]` is the interpolating function, and 5 is the number I chose to try to evaluate it at.

I set `prsol=NDSolve[blah blah]` To evaluate it, I've tried:

```
Evaluate[x1[5]/.prsol]
```

and

```
one[t_]:=x1[t]/.prsol
one[5]
```

Both of these spit out `{x1[5]}` which is contrary to what the F1 Help says it should do.

```
P0h = 1.856*10^7;
V0h = .826063;
T0 = 299.817
g = 9.81;
Aac=.16;
Abe=.025;
Vr=1.067;
Vst=.006306;
Vh[x_] := Vr - x*Aac;
Vl[x_] := Vst + x*Abe;
m1 = 290000;
m4 = 9021;
k3 = 8*10^6;
R = 8.3144621;
Tc = 126.1;
Pc = 3.394*10^6;
ω = .040;
b = .07779607*(R*Tc)/Pc;
Trr[T_] := T/Tc;
κ = .37464 + 1.54226 ω - .26993 ω^2
α[T_] := (1 + κ (1 - Sqrt[Trr[T]]))^2
ac = .45723553*(R^2*Tc^2)/Pc;
a[T_] := ac*α[T]
nh = (P0h*V0h)/(R*T0);
nl = (P0l*V0l)/(R*T0);
Vmolh[x_] := Vh[x]/nh
Vmoll[x_] := Vl[x]/nl

Ppr[x_] := (R*T0)/(Vmolh[x] - b) - 
  a[T0]/(Vmolh[x]^2 + 2*b*Vmolh[x] - b^2)

Fpr[x_] := 
 Aac ((R*T0)/(Vmolh[x] - b) - 
     a[T0]/(Vmolh[x]^2 + 2*b*Vmolh[x] - b^2)) - 
  Abe ((R*T0)/(Vmoll[x] - b) - 
     a[T0]/(Vmoll[x]^2 + 2*b*Vmoll[x] - b^2))

A1 = .1;
ω2 = π/4;
c = 10000;
d = 300000;

ctipmot[t_] := A1 Cos[ω2 t]

prsol = NDSolve[{-c x4'[t] - 
     k3 ((m4 g + Fpr[54/39.3701])/k3 + ctipmot[t] + x4[t]) + 
     Fpr[x1[t] - x4[t] + 54/39.3701] + m4 g == 
    m4 x4''[t], -c x1'[t] - d x1'[t]*Abs[x1'[t]] - 
     Fpr[x1[t] - x4[t] + 54/39.3701] + m1 g == m1 x1''[t], x1[0] == 1,
    x4[0] == 0, x1'[0] == 0, x4'[0] == 0}, {x1[t], x4[t]}, {t, 0, 
   100}]
```

> {{x1[t] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,100.}},<>][t],x4[t] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,100.}},<>][t]}}

```
Plot[Evaluate[x1[t] /. prsol], {t, 0, 32}]
```

^That gives me a graph

```
Evaluate[x1[5] /. prsol]
```

^That gives me:

```
{x1[5]}
```

instead of a value.

Comment: Please provide more details or a minimal working code example that shows the behaviour to increase your chances of getting a helpful answer.

Comment: Thanks! I also want to use the function x1[t] for other things such as plotting the derivative, or plugging that function into another function f(x[t]). How would I do that?

Comment: Thank you everyone! I'm new to this site, clearly, and am not sure how to upvote or whatever the due process is for people helping me out. What am I supposed to do now?

Comment: matt, since no one has actually posted an answer there's not really anything you can do.  Normally you would up-vote any helpful answers, and Accept a (single) fully satisfactory one (you can change which one is Accepted at any time).  These actions would be accomplished by using the up arrow and check-mark to the left of the answer.  You will not be able to vote until you have a bit more [reputation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) but you can still Accept.

Comment: @PlatoManiac Perhaps you would like to post an answer?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard will post once I am back home..may be in an hour!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *Mathematica* when one numerically solves differential equations using `NDSolve` it is often preferable to specify the dependent variables as `{x,y,..}`. In this case the symbols `x`,`y` and so on will each be assigned with an `InterpolatingFunction` object via a `Rule` generated by the `NDSolve` output. Following is an example!

```
s = First@NDSolve[{x'[t] == -y[t] - x[t]^2, y'[t] == 2 x[t] - y[t]^3, 
    x[0] == y[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 20}]
```

> {x->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,20.}},<>],y->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,20.}},<>]}

Now you can plot using

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[k], y[k]} /. s], {k, 0, 20}]
```

Or evaluate the value of the function or its derivatives at certain points as usual.

```
{x[12],y[9],x'[5],y''[15]}/.s
```

> {-0.0801173,0.0557406,-0.386381,-0.379341}

Now what is wrong if you use

```
sBad = First@NDSolve[{x'[t] == -y[t] - x[t]^2, y'[t] == 2 x[t] - y[t]^3, 
    x[0] == y[0] == 1}, {x[[t], y[t]}, {t, 20}]
```

> {x[t]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,20.}},<>][t],y[t]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,20.}},<>][t]}

The main problem is `Rule` is assigning the solution in different format here. So evaluation at a single point becomes more involved which is probably unnecessary.

```
MapThread[#1 /. s /. t -> #2 &, 
         {({x[t], y[t], D[x[t] /. s, t], D[y[t] /. s, {t, 2}]}), {12, 9, 5, 15}}]
```

> {-0.0801173, 0.0557406, -0.386381, -0.379341}

Hence you will need to replace every `x[t]` type expressions and you will need to use the independent variable `t`. Hope I could explain the issues u complained about. I will suggest that you play with the documentation examples more thoroughly as it has tons of useful information varying from basic to advance topics.

BR

Comment: Just to make it explicit for anyone who is as thick as I am: use just the function name, without listing the variables it is a function of, ie, x,not x[t], when naming the dependent variables. Took me a second read-through to figure out what the difference was.